# Suddenly my Apps cannot make HTTPS queries

Tags: java, android, ssl

I was away from Android Studio since January 2018 until June and had gotten to a point where I could make simple Apps which queried an https website, processed the JSON response and updated an UI with slected key-value info.

When I came back, none of these Apps return query  results and the Logcat throws some messages regarding javax ssl certificates like:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

`(...) Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificationException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

One of the Apps not working anymore is the ud843 Soonami starting point from those Udacity free courses. Older Apps like the ud851 Sunshine also do not work anymore.

Even after installing AS 3.1.3 and the Gradle 4.4 and Gradle plugin 3.1.0 and configuring the build.gradle, installing java 8jdk and setting the Environment variables, they do not make the Queries.

I'm not using any proxy, just the same old Home network.

I admit I do not understand much of the answers I read so far, but it seems there has been some sort of change to either the functioning of the WWW or to the way Apps connect to https sites.

From what I've read I can only deduct that we now need to obtain the servers Authenticity Certificates and update the Apps code in order to check for a match when a query connection is attempted.

After reading from [Ãndroid Developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

[Non-Public CA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqRHP.png), I think what I want to do falls under this case.

1. Is this really a requirement nowadays, working with certificates? If so, how can I obtain the certificates in PEM or DER format for this site and query, as an example: [USGS query URL](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/count?starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02) ?
2. If I'm totally mistakened, what am I missing? Can someone explain in a basic way what changed in order to get these Apps to work nowadays?

Comment: is date and time on your device correct?

Comment: which library are you using to send HTTP requests? and post your code from where you are making requests

Comment: @Vlad: Correct in both PC and Emulator and Physical Device -- @ nimi: It's being handled manually, using this code https://github.com/udacity/ud843_Soonami/blob/starting-point/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/soonami/MainActivity.java

Comment: When do the certificates expire?

Comment: Why is that I can make the query using my PC Browser but from within the emulator it does not work?

Comment: @stdunbar: Meanwhile I'm trying to implement that "thing" about importing the certificate into the raw folder and creating a xml resource as well as configuring the manifest. The certificate expires in April 2019. The certificate I imported into raw has .cer extension, is this ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, at least I got them to connect on the Physical mobile devices, no idea on what to do to get them running on the emulator, but that's one less vulnerability on my machine.

What I did meanwhile:
-> downloaded java 8 jdk and set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables;
-> Reinstalled Android Studio, importing settings;
-> changed back to the embedded OpenJDK that comes with android Studio, from Java 8 jdk;
-> deleted all emulatores and created new ones;
-> removed module gradle file indications to use JavaVersion.version_1_8, inside compileOptions;
-> learned how to download the certificate from the https://earthquake.usgs.gov and save it formated as DER while having a .cer extension;
-> created a folder res>raw and in it I saved this certificate;
-> basically I followed the recommendations from Developer.android that I annexed to my question as an image, creating a xml network-security-config and altering the manifest accordingly;

At least the Apps work on the real world mobile devices, don't mind testing them that way.

(with Yoda's voice:) Awfull 2 weeks, these have been.